# Concatenating a list of strings while removing overlaps

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble figuring out this code. I want to create a function that takes a list of strings as input and returns the shortest superstring containing all of the strings in the list. For example,

```
    superstring "fire" "red" "blue" = "firedblue",
```

because the "re" overlaps in "fire" and "red".

I am using a helper function "overlap" to assist in this function:

```
    overlap :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
    x `overlap` y = prefix ++ y
        where (prefix, _) : _ = filter (\(_, match) -> match `isPrefixOf` y) $ zip (inits x) (tails x)
```

The helper function above combines strings in the following way:

```
    overlap "fire" "red" = "fired"
```

I want to use "foldr" and my function "overlap" in creating my superstring, but I'm not sure how to implement it. So far I have:

```
    superstring :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a]
    superstring xs = foldr (\x acc -> x `overlap` xs) "" xs
```

I'm not exactly sure how to implement the foldr function to work in this case, so any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Nitpick: In the first paragraph, I guess you mean shortest, as opposed to "longest"?

Comment: Also: What is `Str`? If `Str a` is just a synonym for `[a]`, you probably should drop it and just write `[a]`.

Comment: Right, I corrected it to "shortest" and changed it to [a]

Comment: You accidentally replaced it with `a`, so I changed it to `[a]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, let's assume your `overlap` function does what you expect. That being so, there is a handful of small issues to deal with. Firstly, if you want `superstring` to deal with all kinds of lists and not just `String` and so give it type...

```
superstring :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a]
```

... then you can't use `""` in its implementation:

```
GHCi> :t ""
"" :: [Char]
```

Just write `[]` instead. Secondly, the binary operation you use for folding should combine the next element of the list (`x`) with the accumulated value (`acc`), as opposed to the input list (`xs`). Applying both changes, `superstring` becomes:

```
superstring :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a]
superstring xs = foldr (\x acc -> x `overlap` acc) [] xs
```

Or, even less verbosely:

```
superstring :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a]
superstring xs = foldr overlap [] xs
```

Thirdly, note that the argument to `superstring` is a list of lists. Making it a function that takes a variable number of arguments, as you suggest in your usage example...

```
superstring "fire" "red" "blue"
```

... requires a few rather complicated tricks you probably don't want to bother with right now, so I suggest you just leave it at that:

```
GHCi> superstring ["fire", "red", "blue"]
"firedblue"
```

Finally, all of what I wrote above assumes that `overlap` does what it says on the tin and that the `superstring` you want to write can be expressed as a straightforward fold. Ultimately it's up to you and your requirements, but I'm not entirely sure that is the case. For instance, consider what happens if you try:

```
superstring ["fire", "red", "blue", "ire"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helps. This solution is ultimately what I wanted this function to do

Comment: This is simply wrong - even with a correct `overlap` function. Consider the expression `foldr overlap [] ["aaab","xaaa","aaax"]`. Clearly we have the following: `"aaab" + ("xaaa" + "aaax") = "aaab" + "xaaax" = "aaabxaaax"` (or `"xaaaxaaab"`!!). A simple fold cannot see that `"aaaxaaa"` is longer than `"xaaax"` but allows you to make a shorter final string by combing the first two that way. `foldl overlap []["aaab","xaaa","aaax"] = "aaaxaaab"` , a shorter string containing all the input strings.

Comment: @user2407038 This is the same limitation I hinted at with the `superstring ["fire", "red", "blue", "ire"]` example at the end of the answer -- a simple fold cannot rearrange the strings to find the order which gives the most overlaps. Given the reaction of the OP, it might be the case that their requirements are in fact less stringent than what the question says. (By the way, `overlap` is associative, and so as far as the result string is concerned it doesn't matter whether you use `foldr` or `foldl`.)

Comment: @user2407038 I suppose author of question wanted just overlap of neighbor elements. Of course, if you want general version of Shortest Superstring to work on your example as you described, you need to implement much difficult algorithm which involves graphs and solution of NP-hard Traveling salesman problem.